# How Do I Add Social Features To App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile, social-networking

This question may be a little broad so of course the answers won't be as specific because of that.

I'm almost finished with developing a basic app but I want to add a social aspect to it. Specifically, I want a follow/followers type feed system that is seen in instagram, intonow, etc.

I looked on google but couldn't find much info on how to add this type of functionality in an app and was hoping you guys could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick one social feature first and implement them one at a time.

Do you want your app to twitter? [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage)

Do you want to update facebook status? [FaceBook API](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Do you want to Foursquare? [Foursquare](http://developer.foursquare.com/)

Once you pick one, then you can ask a question more to the point.

Comment: I know how to implement the stuff you mentioned.  Im really looking to make the account system.  like how to make user accounts, etc.

Comment: Do you have a backend server?  Because when you ask the user for username, password, e-mail address, you need a place to store those accounts.

Comment: No, not at this moment.  Right now all I have is the app which uses CoreData.  Once I know what I need to do the user accounts I can get a server, etc.

Comment: GoogleAppEngine gives you one free instance.  Amazon EC2 is giving away 1 year free. Windows Azure is giving away for free until June 30.

Comment: I'm assuming their are some drawbacks to using one of these as apposed to one that I pay for myself?  Sorry, I'm really new to servers, etc.

Comment: If you paid for server yourself, you will be paying monthly no matter what.  WIth GoogleAppEngine free instance, it's free if you have low usage.  So if you deploy your app and only have 100 users, you wouldn't pay anything.  Once your app becomes popular, like say a million user, the server will scale and then you paid for the high usages.  So if it takes 6 months to get popular, you didn't paid anything. On Amazon EC2 you get one year free.  So you decided, which is better for your start-up application?

Comment: Thanks Black Frog, I have absolutely no experience with this type of stuff.  I only know Objective C and some HTML.  What I want to do is build a login portal where users can see their data from the app.  Fairly simple read only access, nothing editable as of yet.  Can I use the google app engine and create a site that looks nothing like google?  Im trying to mimic the path.com login portal idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to Share Kit :)
http://getsharekit.com

Comment: Thanks Matthew this will definitely come in handy, but I was looking for more info on how to handle user accounts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check Socialize out  http://www.GetSocialize.com .  Full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Parse.

https://www.parse.com/tour

"
With our user management system, you can quickly add user accounts to your app without having to code a full authentication system yourself. Our SDK provides methods to securely sign up and log in your users. This allows your users to access their account from multiple devices.
"

I used Parse for Push notifications, and the SDK was very straightforward.